# Ruby on rails Edit user on Devise without entering the password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know this question has been asked several times already and every answer leads to devise wiki, but I can't get it to work. I followed the wiki and some other posts here, but no luck. I want to let the user update his info (email. username. name, etc) without having to type the password every time.

My `registrations_controller.rb` look like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

and my `routes.rb` look like this:

```
Sparechef::Application.routes.draw do
  get "users/profile"

  devise_for :users
  devise_for :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
  resources :dashboard

  root to: "home#index"

  match "profile" => "users#profile"
end
```

I still get the message "Current password can't be blank". If I update my routes to follow devise wiki with `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }` I get this error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: current_password
```

Does anybody know how to get this to work?

Comment: How about adding attr_accessible to current_password in User ?

Comment: Yeap, that did the trick! thanks Michael.

Comment: `current_password` needs to be in `attr_accessor` in addition to `attr_accessible`. Otherwise you'll get the error `unknown attribute: current_password`.

Answer (score 0):

As per @michael in the question comments above, add `attr_accessible :current_password` in `User`.